# Media queries некорректно работает на смартфонах

Tags: css3

Делаю сайт адаптивным, для этого использую media queries. Используется 2 условия:
**[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) only screen and (max-width: 1020px) and (min-width: 600px)** и **[[@media](/users/3055/mediaportal)](/users/3055/mediaportal) only screen and (max-width: 599px)**. Так вот, на смартфоне с разрешением 800 на 480 почему-то срабатывает первое условие, т.е. грузятся стили для экранов с шириной от 1020px до 600px, нужно, что бы срабатывало второе условие.

Объясните, как так и как исправить?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, нужна ширина рабочей области или типа того.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решил, в хтмл добавляем строчку:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```